# Android JsonObject to Array Example

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to create an application using JsonObject and converts it into Array. Is any example available? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: here is a very good tutorial over JSON : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/x-andbene1/index.html?ca=drs-

Comment: Might help if you show the JSON you want to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I can highly recommend to use [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) (Apache 2.0 license) for dealing with JSON on Android/Java.

To get started just take a look at their [User Guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)

If you have any specific question, please add code snippets, JSON strings or exception stacktraces to your question

-axel